# onClick is not fire on button Click in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

In content page I have one textbox and one button. On button click event I want to display one gridview and this gridview has some javaScript for responsive behaviour. from Gridview I have also use ModelPopupExtender (Ajax) in content page.

**Page directives :**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="UpdateUser.aspx.cs" Inherits="WirelessLCDdisplay.AdminPages.UpdateUser" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script src="../JavaScript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    <!--        // building select nav for mobile width only -->
        $(function () {
            // building select menu
            $('<select />').appendTo('nav');

            // building an option for select menu
            $('<option />', {
                'selected': 'selected',
                'value': '',
                'text': 'Choise Page...'
            }).appendTo('nav select');

            $('nav ul li a').each(function () {
                var target = $(this);

                $('<option />', {
                    'value': target.attr('href'),
                    'text': target.text()
                }).appendTo('nav select');

            });

            // on clicking on link
            $('nav select').on('change', function () {
                window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            });
        });

        // show and hide sub menu
        $(function () {
            $('nav ul li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideDown(150);
        },
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideUp(150);
        }
    );
        });
        //end
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable = no">
    <link href="../css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/jquery.responsivetable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/jquery.responsivetable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setupResponsiveTables();
        });

        function setupResponsiveTables() {
            $('.responsiveTable1').responsiveTable({
                staticColumns: 2,
                scrollRight: false,
                scrollHintEnabled: true,
                scrollHintDuration: 3000
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**TextBox and Button :**

```
<p class="contact">
        <label for="username">
            Username</label></p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUname" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorusername" runat="server" ErrorMessage="User Name required"
        Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtUname" ForeColor="Red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUserDetails" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclick="btnUserDetails_Click1" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" class="buttom" CausesValidation="False"
        OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
```

**Code Behind onClick Event :**

```
protected void btnUserDetails_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindGridData();
        }

private void BindGridData()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username,FirstName,LastName,Email,PhNo,Designation,Department,RollId from tblEmployees where Username=@Username", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUname.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            for (int intCount = 0; intCount < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
            {
                if ((Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount].ItemArray[7])) == "0")
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount].ItemArray[7] = "User";
                }
                else
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount].ItemArray[7] = "Admin";
                }
            }
            da.Fill(ds);
            gvUserDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvUserDetails.DataBind();
        }

**
```

**My onClick="btnUserDetails_Click1" event is not fire 
what is reason behind it??**

Comment: Shouldn't onclick="btnUserDetails_Click1" have a capital O in onClick? Like this OnClick="btnUserDetails_Click1"...

Comment: Should have a capital c to...OnClick. Just like btnReset

Comment: This is not working. By default it takes "onClick" still I am not accessing button event. Is it possible this is happens because of JavaScript that I am place in header.

Comment: I found that in some button (like image button) OnClick event fire and in some button onClick event fire. What is actual difference between OnClick and onClick.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing onclick to OnClick

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUserDetails" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClick="btnUserDetails_Click1" />
```

Comment: This is not working. By default it takes "onClick" still I am not accessing button event. Is it possible this is happens because of JavaScript that I am place in header.

Comment: Downvoting my answer cuz even this ONCLICK works. So looks like Onclick case is not a problem.
edit: Damn it, I can't downvote myself.

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

Tag prefix is 'asp' , why ? Are you using it ?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net there is a two type of button event **`'onclick'`** and **`'OnClick'`**.

`onclick`: This once fire javascript function.
`OnClick`: This one fire your code behind .CS sit server event if we add runat="server" tag on button.

> **NOTE:** 1.On Click Event sends the request to the server and in response performs the action.
>   2. On Client Click is very similar to onclick function which we use to write in Javascript... that is it executes the statements in the
>   client side with out sending it to the server​​